# How do I reflect data in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there an array formula in Excel 2013 (similar to transpose) that will reflect data in a column? See below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in formula for this, but you can use `INDEX` to return a calculated row reference in a range.

Assuming your sample data starts at row 1 (it doen't have to)

For non-dynamic array versions of Excel

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$3,COUNTA($A$1:$A$3)-ROW()+ROW($A$1:$A$3),1)
```

Enter as standard formula in `B1` and copy down.

---

For users who have a version of Excel that includes Dynamic Arrays (not available in V2013), use in `B1`

```
=INDEX(A1:A3,SORT(ROW(A1:A3),1,-1)*1,1)
```

and it will Spill